# PHP - Different results from Browser to file_get_contents

Tags: php

I'm hitting Google Api's to get some geolocations.

The endpoint looks like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=84100+ORANGE+FR&key=apikey

If I open this link on my chrome browser the API will return some data.

If i hit it with file_gets_content or simplexml_load_file il will return "zero results"

After some testing, I found out that I can see results on chrome because the browser itself is set in Italian language. If I set it in English it will return "Zero results" same as PHP.

How can I get in PHP the results I get on Chrome?

Comment: I doubt the API cares about the language.

Comment: But you could try adding the `Accept-language:` header when you call the API. Use DevTools to see what value the browser is sending, and send the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the issue here.

Basically when i set chrome in Italian, it probably rearranged the parameters order, returning me different results.

The actual issue here was the address parameter where City comes before zip.

Also adding the parameter &language=it worked for probably the same reason

So the correct URL would be

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=ORANGE+84100+FR&key=apikey

I spent way to much time debugging this one.

Comment: Such thing is probably documented somewhere...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).